# Converting varchar to date in postgresql (date_parse doesn't work)

Tags: postgresql, presto

Running this existing query in presto:

```
date(date_parse(activation_date, '%%m-%%d-%%Y')) from table1
```

gives the error

> "Invalid format: "02/06/2022""

`Activation_date` is `varchar`, showing `MM/DD/YYYY`

How do I convert it to a date so that I can join it to a column that is already in postgresql date type? Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using `%%` rather than just `%`?  And, why does your pattern contain `-` if your strings contain `/`?

Comment: Postgres supports the `to_date()` method.

Comment: The title contains psotgresql, but the description contains presto. Which SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The expected format is `%m/%d/%Y` in Trino (formerly PrestoSQL).

```
trino> SELECT date(date_parse('02/06/2022', '%m/%d/%Y'));
   _col0
------------
 2022-02-06
```

https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=date_parse#mysql-date-functions

Answer (score 0):

- `date_parse` is not a Postgres function.
- You don't need to escape `%` in Postgres strings.
- Your format has `-` while your string has `/`.

If your [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) is set to `MDY` (Month Day Year), simply cast the string to a date.

```
# SELECT current_setting('datestyle');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 ISO, MDY

# select '02/06/2022'::date;
    date    
------------
 2022-02-06
```

See [Date/Time Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) for more.